# Exclude signifcance "stars" in aprstable{aprstable}?

Tags: r

By default, `aprstable()` prints out the the "stars" denoting levels of significance. Is there any way to drop them altogether?

Comment: Since this isn't a base R function, please add a reference to the packages needed to reproduce your code, i.e. `library(...)`

Comment: Did you already try `stars=FALSE`?

Comment: Sleep deprivation. Thanks, mrdwab.

Comment: @user702432, I've added it as an answer since it actually isn't mentioned in the package documentation as far as I can see.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as correct. Thanks, mrdwab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aprstable()` manual doesn't specifically mention it, but you can use `stars=FALSE` to get rid of the stars. By default it only looks for `1` or `default`, so it might even be possible to enter something like `stars=3` and still get a table with no significance stars.

If you enter something like `stars=NULL`, you'll get the following error message, which led me to my answer:

```
Error in if (signif.stars && stars == "default") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```